# How do I show graphs and KPIs from an OLAP cube in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, olap, kpi

I need to display content from an OLAP cube in Sharepoint. This could be done using PerformancePoint Server but unfortunately Microsoft has decided to drop support for that product some time ago. Their plan is to integrate some of the functionality directly into the next version of Sharepoint instead. The problem is that I can't wait that long and it would not be wise to base the solution on abondoned software.

How can I solve this, should I use Excel Services and/or how can I do this?

How would you solve it?

With regards
Marcus Lindholm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services 2008 integrated with sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

One resource that I have found useful is this - and yes i would use Excel Services

[Excel Services step-by-step guides: white paper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263430.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you. It was a very useful link.